# Disposable Encrypted Partition

Tags: linux, filesystems, encryption

I'd like to create one-time encrypted partition with a random key which will be wiped on reboot. I found a manual about swap encryption, but swap is just a block device which doesn't have any file system on it. Also I found full system encryption which is unacceptable, I want only one partition. Both methods are not my case.

How to create one? As far as I understand (I'm not Linux professional) I can't directly use fstab/crypttab directly because I need to format the partition after creation every time when the machine is booting up. A kind of script? Are there any pitfalls?

EDIT: Not sure if type of encryption (block/filesystem) matters so long as any saved data is encrypted. If distrib matters: Debian Stretch. TLDR: I want clean ext4 partition mounted somewhere after reboot which data is encrypted by random key.

Comment: You want an encrypted *partition* or an encrypted *filesystem*?  Linux-only?

Comment: Reformatting the partition every time you boot up means nothing on that partition will be saved after shutting down. Have you considered just using a strong password with whole disk encryption and not using that password for anything else?

Comment: Have a look into `dm-crypt`, you can set up an encrypted partition to use, say `/dev/urandom` as a keyfile (Causing the partition to effectively be useless on reboot). However no matter what, you will need to format the partition during boot.

Comment: Yes, the idea is keeping data only while runnning without any possibility of recovering after reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swap is actually very close to what you want — with swap, you put the `swap` flag in `/etc/crypttab`, which tells the boot up scripts to run `mkswap` on the block device at boot.

You basically want the same thing, but with `mkfs` instead of `mkswap`. At least here, that's already supported with the `tmp[=fstype]` flag. You can check the manual page (`man 5 crypttab`) to see what's supported on your system.

So, this should work:

```
some_name /dev/sdaX /dev/urandom cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=512,tmp=ext4
```

and then in `/etc/fstab`, you'd mount `/dev/mapper/some_name` wherever.

BTW: An alternative is tmpfs, which keeps the data in memory. Probably swapable, though, so you'll need either no swap or encrypted swap.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm.

I considered tmpfs but it requires a tons of efforts to fit the amount of data into memory (it is possible but too hard).